# Split View Controller displayed from a tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm having an xcode project where the the root view is a tab bar controller. The first item of a tab bar is a view controller accessed as a navigation controller's root view controller. The second item of the tab bar is a navigation controller whose root view controller is a splitviewcontroller. When I select the second item, the warning message that I get is

```
<SplitViewController: 0x7fceea530640> is expected to have a view controller at index 0 before it's used!
```

The view remains blank. The first tab bar selection works fine. I have [attached](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ic2upldim3crjd3/collection-view-test.zip?dl=0) the project for your perusal. Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

In your MainWindow.xib you specify a nib name to load for the DummyViewController but you don't specify anything for the SplitViewController.  You've told the tab bar controller what kind of object to use (SplitViewController) but nothing about how it should create child view controllers for that object.

This results in a SplitViewController with no view controllers to use, therefore the error message.

Comment: The splitview controller is part of the storyboard. Is there a way i can set the nib name equivalent? Should i set it programatically?

Comment: I don't know of any way to reference something internal to a storyboard from inside a .xib file.  It might work programatically if you take the split view reference out of the .xib and add a new tab with the storyboard view controller.  The bigger problem is making this work at all since it's explicitly not supported.  From Apple docs: "**A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you create. In other words, you must always install the view from a UISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s window.**"